# How to identify whether snapshot of volume contains boot info in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

How can I identify if the snapshot contains boot info through API? I don't want to test by making an attempt to create VM. I didn't find any attribute to detect if the snapshot contains boot info. Please help

Answer (score 1):

This information is not available.

An **Amazon EBS snapshot** contains a backup of the blocks of an Amazon EBS volume. AWS has no idea what is on the disk, because block storage is managed by the operating system used on the virtual machine.

The `DescribeSnapshots()` command provides this information:

```
{
    'Snapshots': [
        {
            'DataEncryptionKeyId': 'string',
            'Description': 'string',
            'Encrypted': True|False,
            'KmsKeyId': 'string',
            'OwnerId': 'string',
            'Progress': 'string',
            'SnapshotId': 'string',
            'StartTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'State': 'pending'|'completed'|'error',
            'StateMessage': 'string',
            'VolumeId': 'string',
            'VolumeSize': 123,
            'OwnerAlias': 'string',
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'string',
                    'Value': 'string'
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
    'NextToken': 'string'
}
```

There is no indication of disk contents nor even the filesystem that is used.

If you are making snapshots of boot volumes, you can create an **Amazon Machine Image (AMI)**. An AMI is always bootable and also stores an identifier of whether it is Windows or not. An AMI is effectively the same as a snapshot, but it contains some extra metadata and can contain multiple disks.

Comment: That means There is no way other than making a attempt to create VM. Can I detect if volume contains boot info?

Comment: The contents of the snapshot is only accessible by restoring it to an Amazon EBS volume.

Comment: I converted it to ebs volume but still not able to identify if the volume contains boot info.

Comment: It is just a normal disk. Do whatever you would do to a normal disk on a normal computer. Presumably, you'd look at block zero: [The BIOS/MBR Boot Process](https://neosmart.net/wiki/mbr-boot-process/)